# Google Chrome no carga por completo el archivo css

Tags: html5, css3, google-chrome, sass

apenas estoy aprendiendo este tema de desarrollo web y me acaba de pasar lo siguiente

subí en mi servidor la web que estoy trabajando, pero solo en Chrome no funciona el css que genera Sass, en los demás navegadores funciona sin problema, lo que alcanzó a notar es que Chrome carga el archivo solo hasta la línea 72, no pasa de hay, está es la web

[www.advecu.com](http://www.advecu.com)

Comment: Chrome es un navegador ya estandarizado para soportar CSS3 y las propiedades actuales. Acabo de entrar a tu página y carga todo correctamente. Aquí una pregunta ¿No será el caché? Prueba presionando Ctrl + F5. Si esto sigue sin dar resultado, sería de gran ayuda que nos muestres tu código, a veces puede ser también un error de Sintaxis. Además, si ha aplicado prioridades como `transform` o `transition` y no has incluido los prefijos puede que tú CSS no sea compatible con todos los navegadores: https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: El sitio web lo veo perfecto, sin problemas en el CSS, como te dicen en el primer comentario, borrá caché y probá de nuevo

Comment: Yo veo perfecto [el sitio web](https://i.gyazo.com/af6dca28ae0b2a88a87a74efae443359.png)

Comment: a mi me carga perfecto que tal si desintalas tu google chrome y limpiaz tu pc y reinstalas .. a lo mejor alguna basurita o extencion te esta jodiendo suele pasar

Comment: Funciono perfecto el Crtl + F5, lo que pasaba era que lo probé en varios equipos diferentes y en todos tenía el mismo problema, pero no tome en cuenta que en esos equipos ya había abierto la web antes y seguro quedó el caché igual, les agradezco mucho!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Entre a tu sitio web y veo que carga bien el css.
tienes un archivo Css llamado: **estiloscss.css**
Y al examinarlo veo que llega hasta la linea: 529

.bg-navColorPropio {
background-color: #0E0E0E; }

Revisa tu cache o tal vez si lo estas corriendo en localhost, puede que estés apuntando a otro proyecto.

Comment: Tu respuesta puede ser de utilidad, sin embargo, debería ser un comentario, porque puede ser de utilidad no la voy a calificar. La pregunta del OP está mal planteada con pocos intentos de solución y sería mejor esperar a que el OP actualize su pregunta y diga que problema específico causa. En este caso, tu respuesta puede ser de utilidad ya que estoy de acuerdo contigo de que pueda ser el caché.

Comment: Lo del cache ya se le dijo en 3! comentarios.. creo que la respuesta sobra hasta saber que pasa realmente....

Comment: Respuesta y comentarios parecen ser simultaneos ...